# How do I get a VBA function to use the current query as an argument in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I have a function that I use to open a query into a new and unnamed Excel spreadsheet from a form control, using the onclick event of the control to hardcode the query as the argument of the function, like this

```
`Call OpenExcelCurrent("Points_Totals")`
```

Users can then save the spreadsheet or not, as they wish.

What I would like to do is make this function dynamic and available via the Autokeys macro so that when I use the keystroke it runs the function against the query I am working on to produce a spreadsheet, then when I switch tabs to another query I can use the keystroke again to get another.

My question is, how do I get the function to look at the query that is currently open so that I can run my function on it? After digging around I am guessing I need to do something with "acQuery" somehow but it is beyond me at the moment! Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

The function that I am using for the onclick event is below. I freely admit that this was taken from another answer here and tweaked slightly as my coding ability is relatively low.

```
`Public Function OpenExcelCurrent(MyQueryName)
'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
'Step 2: Identify the database and query
Set MyDatabase = CurrentDb
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs(MyQueryName) 'Query name in the database, needs     to be in quotation marks under button_click event
'Step 3: Open the query
Set MyRecordset = MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset
'Step 4: Clear previous contents
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
.Visible = True
.Workbooks.Add
.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
'Step 5: Copy the recordset to Excel
.ActiveSheet.Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset
'Step 6: Add column heading names to the spreadsheet
For i = 1 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).value = MyRecordset.Fields(i - 1).Name
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 178, 102)
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Font.Size = 11
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Font.Bold = True
Next i
xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.Font.Size = 10
End With
'MsgBox "Your spreadsheet will need to be saved in a location of your choice",     vbInformation, "Reminder"
End Function`
```

Cheers,
Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graham,

I think all you need do is instead of passing in the query name as a parameter to your function, instead just reference Application.CurrentObjectName.

So...

```
Public Function OpenExcelCurrent()
```

...

```
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs(Application.CurrentObjectName)
```

That should get the name of the query you have highlighted when you run your macro.

You may want to have some logic in your code to make sure the currently selected object is actually a query, to avoid any nasty errors if you accidentally run the macro whilst having another object selected.

Let me know if this works.

Ash

Comment: Thanks for taking the time ro answer Ash,  it's a work DB so I will try it out on Monday and let you know what happens!

Comment: Hi Ash, I have amended my function as you suggested and it now works just as I wanted it to! My next challenge is the check to make sure it is a query I am launching the function on! Thanks again
Graham

Comment: Glad I could help Graham. If you haven't already would you mark my answer as your accepted solution. Thanks, Ash